# Remove "chapter 1" and have just 1 in the report

Tags: sectioning, chapters

In the beginning of a new chapter, Latex have

Chapter 1

XXXXXXXXXX

instead of this format i want to have

1

XXXXXXXXXX

can you pls suggest how to customize the chapter?

Thanks in advance

Comment: which class are you using? With `scrbook` and `scrreprt` it is as easy as `\documentclass[chapterprefix]{scrbook}
\renewcommand*\chapterformat{\thechapter}`

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`titlesec`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/titlesec) package:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
  {\normalfont\huge\bfseries}{\thechapter}{20pt}{\Huge}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Without any packages, you can redefine `\@makechapterhead` as defined in `report.cls`:

```
\documentclass{report}

\makeatletter
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
  \vspace*{50\p@}%
  {\parindent \z@ \raggedright \normalfont
    \ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
        \huge\bfseries\thechapter
        \par\nobreak
        \vskip 20\p@
    \fi
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Huge \bfseries #1\par\nobreak
    \vskip 40\p@
  }}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 5):

The following example patches `\@makechapterhead`, the macro that formats the chapter title in class `report`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}{\@chapapp\space}{}{%
}{%
  \errmessage{Patching \string\@makechapterhead\space failed}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}   
\chapter{XXXXXXXXXX}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]